# How to display data into an asp:Repeater from two different SharePoint List programmatically

Tags: development, sharepoint-addin, asp.net

So basically, I am new in Sharepoint Development and I am having a hard time using asp:Repeater. I want to display all the data from one SharePoint List and find some of its related field in the other List using some kind of Primary Key to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `Lookup Columns` in SharePoint for list relationships.

Once you have setup a lookup column you can use CAML to query data from two lists, even columns from both the lists can be included in one.

[List Joins and Projections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee539975(v=office.14).aspx)

Once you get the `SPListItemCollection` you can convert it into `DataTable` using [`SPListItemCollection.GetDataTable()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitemcollection.getdatatable.aspx) method to bind it to `asp:Repeater` control. You can also bind `SPListItemCollection` object to `asp:Repeater` but if you convert it to `DataTable`, you can find many examples from ASP.NET forums.